# Is it possible to make an add-on menu item bold?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have one option in my menu that is not the first step but it is the primary menu item people will need to go to.  I was wondering if there was a way I could make just that item bold.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. I haven't seen any way to do this in the reference guide. Would be a cool feature.